# How to change (CQ5) VLT repo url/port?

Tags: aem

I have checked out vlt repo using:

```
vlt co http://localhost:4502/crx/-/jcr:root path/to/repo --force
```

But now, my CQ instance changed location (port). Is there a way to set new URL(port) to vlt?
(without checking out again)

I have tried unzipping `path/to/repo/.vlt` and changing `repository.url` file sometimes it works, but in most cases it breaks local repo, or I'm unable to unzip.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're looking for something like the ["svn relocate" command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html). This is not possible with the VLT tool directly.

Options (any one of these should do it):

- I recommend checking out a new copy of the repository and reapplying the changes that show from running "vlt status" over there.
- Set up a new CQ server on the old port, then use ["vlt rcp"](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/2-2/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool.html#Rcp). The process would probably be: copy the whole repository from old to new server, push your local stuff to the new server, copy part of the tree from new to old.
- The repository.url setting is nested in .vlt files under all subdirectories of the repository. You could try a global/recursive search & replace for all of these. I've never tried this though. For example, something like this: (I get permission denied running this, needs more work.)

  `find -name .vlt -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/localhost:4502/localhost:4503/g'`
- Remove all the .vlt files and use the vlt import/export commands to load. See the "Using import/export instead of .vlt control" section of this document: http://wem.help.adobe.com/enterprise/en_US/10-0/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool.html